# Regular Expression Matcher

Tags: regex, docx

I am using pattern matching to match file extension with my expression String for which code is as follows:-

```
public static enum FileExtensionPattern
{
    WORDDOC_PATTERN( "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(txt|docx|doc))$)" ), PDF_PATTERN(
        "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(pdf))$)" );

    private String pattern = null;

    FileExtensionPattern( String pattern )
    {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String getPattern()
    {
        return pattern;
    }
}

pattern = Pattern.compile( FileExtensionPattern.WORDDOC_PATTERN.getPattern() );
        matcher = pattern.matcher( fileName );
        if ( matcher.matches() )
            icon = "blue-document-word.png";
```

when file name comes as "Home & Artifact.docx" still matcher.matches returns false.It works fine with filename with ".doc" extension.

Can you please point out what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Home & Artifact.docx" contains spaces. Since you allow any char except whitespaces `[^\s]+`, this filename is not matched.

Try this instead:

```
(.+?(\.(?i)(txt|docx|doc))$
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is because you have spaces in filename (`"Home & Artifact.docx"`) but your regex has `[^\\s]+` which won't allow any spaces.**

Use this regex instead for `WORDDOC_PATTERN`:

```
"(?i)^.+?\\.(txt|docx|doc)$"
```